# Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition is region specific?

Tags: magento2-enterprise

Hi Guys i am facing problem about Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition question Magento that  Enterprise Cloud Edition is region specific ? and is Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition is Available  US Region  only ?  can anyone explain it.

Answer (score 2):

MECE can be hosted in any AWS region **excepting the Govcloud and China**. Development clusters exist in US and EU.

Robert Douglass, MECE team

Comment: Thank you for yours feedback but i want to know about the magento ready made solution with AWS etc that they called as " Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition".